# How to change an update query from mysql to pdo?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am using the bellow query to update but now I tried to change it to pdo and it failed to work 
Please any help will  be appreciated

```
 function updateonlinesession(){            
    if(isset($_SESSION['username']['id'])){
    $uid = $_SESSION['username']['id'];
    $page = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $username = $_SESSION['logged'];

    mysql_query("UPDATE site_user SET dateupdated  = now(),ip = '$ip' WHERE 
    username = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['username'])."'"); 
    }

    }
```

Here is what I tried with pdo

```
function updateonlinesession(){         
if(isset($_SESSION['username']['id'])){
$uid = $_SESSION['username']['id'];
$page = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$username = $_SESSION['logged'];

$update = ("UPDATE site_user SET dateupdated  = now(),ip = '$ip' WHERE 
username = '".($_SESSION['username'])."'");
$sth_update= $con->prepare($update);
$sth_update->execute();
}

}

?>
```

Comment: Post what you have tried...

Comment: have a gander: http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

Comment: this thread talks about `sql injection` but it shows the ways to use prepared statements and one of these is PDO, [How to prevent SQL injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Why is this upvoted while the OP hasn't provided any prove of effort? Besides there are tons of articles/answers that covers this topic. It seems to me like `give me the code`

Comment: @HamZa DzCyberDeV I put it chaeck now I edited after Mr Chris  and Eggplant requested

Comment: @HamZa DzCyberDeV I suspect the upvotes are being done in the hope that the question gains some visibility and serves as an example for novice PHP developers. Anything to stop them using the mysql extension!

Comment: @KenKeenan I hope that's the case :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE site_user SET dateupdated=now(), ip=? WHERE username=?");
$stmt->execute(array($ip, $_SESSION['username']));
$affected_rows = $stmt->rowCount();
```

where `$db` is your connection

again: [A great tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers)

Comment: No problem, good luck on making the switch, believe me its worth the effort in learning PDO. and that tutorial helps a lot.

Answer (score 5):

```
// connetion
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass);

// query
$sql = "UPDATE site_user SET dateupdated = NOW(), ip = ?
        WHERE username = ?";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($ip, $_SESSION['username']);
```

Answer (score 5):

First, connect somewhere in a bootstrap/config file:

```
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=test;host=localhost;charset=utf8';
$opt = array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
);
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);
```

then, run your query

```
function updateonlinesession(){
    global $pdo;
    if(isset($_SESSION['username']['id'])){
        $sql = "UPDATE site_user SET dateupdated=now(),ip=? WHERE username=?"; 
        $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $pdo->execute(array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $_SESSION['logged']));
    }
}
```

Make sure that all variables you're using have proper values (`var_dump($_SESSION)` is enough)

Comment: you really a star u always help me Great Man

Answer (score 2):

```
function updateonlinesession(){
    if(isset($_SESSION['username']['id'])){
        $uid = $_SESSION['username']['id'];
        $page = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $username = $_SESSION['logged'];

        //Establish your PDO object.
        $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb", "username", "password");

        //Prepare your statement.
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE site_user SET dateupdate = now(), ip = ? WHERE username = ?");
        $stmt->execute(array(
            $ip,
            $_SESSION['username']
        ));
        $stmt->closeCursor();
    }
}
```